# How to prove this equation holds in a ring?

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory

I am struggling on the highlighted part of this question.

[image]

Here is what I have attempted.

$$a+bw+bx=a+bw+b(2-w)=a+bw+2b=bw=a+2b~~~~(1)$$ but then equating the right hand side of with what we want to show gives $a+2b=c+7d$.

Now I'm not too sure on how to show that we can express $a+2b$ as $c+7d$ for $c \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $d \in \Bbb{Z}$.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you better write it down (not copy), otherwise some may not be willing to open an unknown link.

Comment: I wanted to embed as I'm not very good at $\LaTeX$ and it is very inefficient I am new to the site so did not know this was frowned upon, I thought I could just upload the image but it doesn't let me.

Comment: Is it just division theorem for integers?

Comment: Yes, or pigeonhole principle

Answer (score 0):

umm... $a$ and $b$ are integers, so why doesn't dividing $a+2b$ by $7$ work? $c$ should be in $\{0, 1, \dots , 6\}$ - why is $7$ even a needed choice for $c$?

Oh, I see, you just posted the homework assignment... I see the teacher had it right, $7$ is not among the choices for $c$, you added that.

Comment: Fixed. Thank you. Could you explain how to carry on with this question?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: @abiessu Would this be just a simple application of the division theory?

Comment: @abiessu - care to elaborate? How îs that not a complete answer?

Comment: @mathguy: it does not provide an answer to the question, and the content appears to ask for clarification rather than provide helpful information

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Divide $a+2b$ by 7, $c$ is the remainder and $d$ is the quotient. What's missing?

Comment: Perhaps re-reading the last couple sentences of the question and then reformulating your content as an answer to that would help.  Perhaps writing about the pigeonhole principle or the Euclidean algorithm would be effective.